# How to import and build TDLib project in Intellij for Java language and fix dll problems?

Tags: java, tdlib

I would like to import [TDLib](https://github.com/tdlib/td) project in Intellij and build it using Java language but the documentation is not well written. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my step by step guide how you can build TDLib project following the bellow steps which took me a couple of hours to do it.

First go to [**this address**](https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html?language=Java) and select your language which here is Java and Operating system and so on.

[image]

Then you will see a list of commands which you have to run them one by one or copy all of them and paste them in windows Powershell.

[image]

After executing commands it will download neccessary files and will build the project.

Your project tab in intellij will look like this:

[image]

In this step you have finished building TDlib project.

The second step is to solve size problem for `TdApi.java` file:

```
 File size exceeds configured limit (2560000), code insight features not available
```

Solution:
In Intellij Go to Menu Help > Edit Custom Properties
and add this line:

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=25000
```

At this step you shouldn't have compile time error. Go to this path and run the project `example/java/org/drinkless/tdlib/example/Example.java`.

I was facing bellow runtime error:

```
TDLib UnsatisfiedLinkError (no tdjni in java.library.path)
```

For fixing this problem I just copied all the .dll files inside `D:\~\td\tdlib\bin` folder to `D:\~\td\example\java\td\bin` folder.

Another error I faced after running the project again was the bellow one:

```
tdjni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Which I could fix it by copying all the `.dll` files inside this folder `D:\~\td\example\java\td\bin` to `C:\Windows\System32` folder.

Then I could run the project successfully.

Hope this become helpful and save your time a bit.