# How to use TDLib (Telegram Database Library) with JAVA and Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, telegram, tdlib

I am trying to use Telegram Database Library (TDLib) to create my own web client for Telegram using Spring-boot and IntelliJ.
Using the following documentation I was able to build and run the Example.java on my linux terminal:

TDLib Documentation : https://core.telegram.org/tdlib 
TDLib GitHub : https://github.com/tdlib/td/ 
TDLib Java Example GitHub : https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java 
TDLib GitHub Java Example build instructions : https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html?language=Java

**CONFIGURATION:**
Choose a programming language from which you want to use TDLib: **JAVA**

Choose an operating system on which you want to use TDLib: **Linux**

Choose a Linux distro on which you want to use TDLib: **Ubuntu 20**

**INSTRUCTIONS:**

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get install make git zlib1g-dev libssl-dev gperf php-cli
 cmake default-jdk g++
 git clone https://github.com/tdlib/td.git
 cd td
 rm -rf build
 mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=../example/java/td -DTD_ENABLE_JNI=ON ..
 cmake --build . --target install
 cd ..
 cd example/java
 rm -rf build
 mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=../../../tdlib -DTd_DIR:PATH=$(readlink -e ../td/lib/cmake/Td) ..
 cmake --build . --target install
 cd ../../..
 cd ..
 ls -l td/tdlib
```

Using the given below Stackoverflow post I tried running the downloaded td-library to import and build the project in IntelliJ for Java : [How to import and build TDLib project in Intellij for Java language and fix dll problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546868/how-to-import-and-build-tdlib-project-in-intellij-for-java-language-and-fix-dll)

I am getting the following error on IntelliJ while running Example.java:

**ERROR:**

```
/home/yashdeepsingh/.jdks/jbrsdk-17.0.9/bin/java -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-community/473/lib/idea_rt.jar=39397:/snap/intellij-idea-community/473/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/yashdeepsingh/PROJECT/td/out/production/td org.drinkless.tdlib.example.Example
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no tdjni in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2434)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
    at org.drinkless.tdlib.Client.<clinit>(Client.java:18)
    at org.drinkless.tdlib.example.Example.main(Example.java:302)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void org.drinkless.tdlib.Client.nativeClientSetLogMessageHandler(int, org.drinkless.tdlib.Client$LogMessageHandler)'
    at org.drinkless.tdlib.Client.nativeClientSetLogMessageHandler(Native Method)
    at org.drinkless.tdlib.Client.setLogMessageHandler(Client.java:161)
    at org.drinkless.tdlib.example.Example.main(Example.java:302)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I want to use the TDLib java code to further develop my own client in a different Springboot project.

How should I proceed next? Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after building the files by following the build instructions mentioned here[https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldzKn.png)

also to build you need to install cmake prior

then it will generate some build files like below

[image]

then you can copy all those build files to the td\example\java folder

then set vm arguments like below

[image]

now you can run the example class

would be happy to share more details if still facing issues